# javascript variables returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, console, worldpay

I am working with some javscript at the moment, the basic thought process behind it is that, you click a link and that links produces and  entry in a basket, I currently logged what gets sent to the basket in my console. When I click a link it triggers the `additem()` function,

```
function additem(desc,price,quantity)
    {

        var x = items.length - 1;
        var found = (x == 0);
        var y = new Item(desc,price,parseInt(quantity));
        console.log(y);
        var z = y;

        while((x != 0) && (found == false))
        {
            z = items[x];

            if(z != null)
            {
                if(z.M_desc == desc)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    x--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                x--;
            }
        }

        if(found == false)
        {
            items[++numitems] = y;
        }
        else
        {
            items[x].M_quantity += quantity;
        }

        updatecart();
    }
```

What I see in the console is the following,

```
Item { M_desc="Item 2", M_price="10", M_quantity=1}
```

however when I click into it, I get the following ,

```
M_desc
    "Item 2"

M_price
    "10"

M_quantity
    undefined
```

How can M_quantity be 1 and then undefined in another console view?

===== EDIT =====

I think the problem stems form here, my JS code starts with the line.

```
var items = new Array(2);
```

now I assume that this creates a new array as when I run `console.log(items)` straight after it I get `[undefined, undefined]`.

additem is called on the click of a link using the following code,

HTML

```
<a class='product' rel='"+category[i].product[j].price+"' href=''>"+ category[i].product[j].description + "</a>
```

JS

```
$('.product').live("click",function(e){
    additem($(this).text(), $(this).attr('rel'), 1);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is when the problems arise as `items[x]` is either always null or undefined. and I not sure why.

Comment: You have to provide a test case, so that we can verify this observation. What's `Item`? How do you call `additem()` from the console and "on click"?

Comment: That's still not enough to answer the question. I don't know the context of your "HTML". Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), with the **relevant** code? Also, what's the exact code you use in the JavaScript console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/dg974/ there is js fiddle, click on one of the items and it should create a basket at the bottom with a quantity input and update the total cost, however it does non of this and I believe it is down what item is returning, or how items is being set.

Comment: Your code is a real mess. You're using `eval` and `with` where it's definitely not needed. Also, you're using `.append()` in the wrong way: `.append("<TD>")` `.append('<P>')` and `.append('</TD>')` will **not** result in `<td><p></p></td>`. After these observations, I did not bother to dig deeper in the function logic, since the code itself is flawed already.

Comment: the code is not mine! It is from Worldpay themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Your updatecart function is being called almost simultaneously. `items[i].M_quantity = $('input[name="qty"]').val()` is the problematic line. The input is null and is replacing your quantity with undefined.